# paired Wilcoxon rank test but with 3 groups

Tags: r, anova, wilcoxon-signed-rank

What is the statistical test I should use if I want to run a paired sample Wilcoxon’s signed rank test but I have three groups to compare instead of two?

Comment: What are you trying to find out? If all three are different from each other? Or if one is different from another given the third as a reference? Or something else

Comment: if one is different from another given the third as a reference

Comment: @confused_individual What do you mean by "as a reference"?

Comment: first do a friedman test and than a paired wilcoxon rank test with p.adj like bonferoni
see: https://www.statology.org/friedman-test-r/